# JavaScript Send JSON to Google API

Tags: javascript, json, google-api

I am new to the Google API (Calendar V3) and I have the authorization through obtaining a token working.  I am using a get request to get the users calendar_Id in which I want to send in a POST request in order to add an event to the calendar.

Here is what I am working with:

```
        var json_body = {
           "end": {
             "date": "2013-09-06"
           },
           "start": {
           "date": "2013-09-06"
           },
           "summary": "test event 1"
        };

        var json_string = JSON.stringify(json_body);
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        http.setRequestHeader("Authorization","Bearer " + access_key);
        http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

        http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
                if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                        alert("in here");
                        alert(http.responseText);
                }
        }
        http.send(json_string);
```

The response I am getting is:

```
{
  "error": {
  "errors": [
{
   "domain": "global",
    "reason": "parseError",
   "message": "Parse Error"
}
],
"code": 400,
"message": "Parse Error"
}
}
```

I know that the access_key authorization header is correct since it is not giving me the authorization error.  I have ran this JSON structure in Googles API Explorer tool and it adds an element to my calendar correctly.  I am assuming that the way I am building my JSON is incorrect.  Any ideas?

### Edit

I found the correct solution.  I was misusing a parameter in the url request.  The code above works in case anyone stumbles upon this for reference in the future.

Comment: you seem to be sending the json_body and not the json_string that results from this line `var json_string = JSON.stringify(json_body);`.  Is this bit of code correct?

Comment: Sorry, left the stringify in there because I was testing it.  If I use the stringify version, I get a 404 Not found error instead of a 400 parse error

Comment: OK, got it! Can you expand on where you are sending your request to? ie the URL your are POSTing to.  I am guessing it is of the format: `POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{YOUR_CALENDAR_ID}/events?key={YOUR_API_KEY}`.  Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct, althought I am leavin the 'key=' portion off since I believe that is for applications and my Get requests do not need this.  I am using the access_key to gain access.

Comment: It works!  I found that I was duplicating a parameter in the url.  For reference, the http.send(json_string) was the correct method.